# How to set a child's margin-top based on parent's height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I'm having problems on an old university exam.
Basically it asks to:

take this json file

```
[
    {"colore": "#FF0080", "pos_orizz": 10, "pos_vert": 30},
    {"colore": "#800080", "pos_orizz": 30, "pos_vert": 40},
    {"colore": "#808000", "pos_orizz": 50, "pos_vert": 50},
    {"colore": "#408080", "pos_orizz": 60, "pos_vert": 60},
    {"colore": "#C0C0C0", "pos_orizz": 30, "pos_vert": 50}
]
```

create a function that, using the data contained in the json file, draws square divs in the "main" (the parent).

The dimensions of the divs are: 10% x 10% of the viewport;
position and background colour are specified in the json file (positions are in percentage of the size of the main)

I did everything but, of course, when i give my divs the style specs, the margin-top percentage is relative to the parent's width...and that cause every sort of overflow problems

```
async function crea(){

    const response = await MyFetch();
    
    const main = document.querySelector("main");

    response.forEach(element => {

        let div = document.createElement("div");

        div.style.width = "10vh";
        div.style.height = "10vh";
        div.style.backgroundColor = element.colore;
        **div.style.marginTop  = element.pos_vert+"%";**
        div.style.marginLeft  = element.pos_orizz+"%";

        main.appendChild(div);

    });

}
```

That's my function and i know for sure there's something i can do to make that work, i hope i've been clear in the exposition of the problem

Comment: I'd recommend using `style.position = "absolute"` instead of setting margins

Comment: I tried with position absolute too but the problem remains the same, the divs are not in the right positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example snippet that demonstrates the CSS to use draw square divs on a parent div. In this demo I have set the position in CSS, but you will need to do this in JavaScript

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: gray;
}
div div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>A<div>B</div></div>
```

Comment: I tested it but the problem is that "top" and "left" are in relation with the root element, so when i do it it simply move my div 50px right and 50px bottom in relation to the root, and not to the parent.
I don't know if i've been clear, sorry

Comment: @AndMas There is a simple fix to this "relation" issue you have encountered. You simply have to add a DIV parent and set `position: relative` on it (but don't change any of the "relative" values). Now that you've done this, you can use `position : absolute` on the sub divs and they will be relative to the parent div

Comment: it works, thanks a lot man i was lost.
Thank you again